# Ajax not working for second time for duplicate value

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

While I am submitting this form via ajax it gets only the fist item. I am new so from the last three day I am looking on the web for a solution bit field. please someone help me.

```
<?php
        include  'db.php';

        $result = $mysqli -> query("SELECT * FROM AlmeenaShop LIMIT 8 ");
        if($result -> num_rows <1){
        /*echo"<h2 >No Record Found</h2>";*/
        }else{




        ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Insert data in MySQL database using Ajax</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div style="margin: auto;width: 60%;">
        <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" id="success" style="display:none;">
          <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">×</a>
        </div>
        <?php foreach ($result as $row ) { ?>
        <form id="fupForm" name="form1" method="post">

            <div class="single-products">
                            <div class="productinfo text-center"><img width="200" height="250" alt="" src="<?php  echo  $row['ImageLocation'] ; ?> " />
                                <?php if ($row['OfferPrice']>0): ?>
                                <h2><?php  echo "&#2547; ".  $row['OfferPrice']  ." /-"; ?><del class="text-primary"><?php  echo "&#2547; ".  $row['SalesPrice']  ." /-"; ?></del></h2>
                                <?php else : ?>
                                <h2><?php  echo "&#2547; ".  $row['SalesPrice']  ." /-"; ?></h2>
                                <?php endif ?>

                                <p><?php  echo  $row['ProductName'] ; ?></p>
                                <p><input type="number" name="ProductQuantity" value="1" id="ProductQuantity<?php  echo  $row['StoreID'] ; ?>"  step="1"></p>
                                <p><input type="hidden" id="StoreID<?php  echo  $row['StoreID'] ; ?>" name="StoreID" value="<?php  echo  $row['StoreID'] ; ?>"></p>

                            </div>
                        </div>
            <input type="button" name="target" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save to database" id="<?php  echo  $row['StoreID'] ; ?>">
        </form>
    </div>

            <?php
            } /* FOr Whole Loop*/
            }/* for if then else loop*/

            ?>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('.btn').on('click', function() {
            var target = $(".btn").attr("id");
            $("#"+target).attr("disabled", "disabled");

            var StoreID = $('#StoreID'+target).val();
            var ProductQuantity = $('#ProductQuantity'+target).val();


            if(StoreID!="" && ProductQuantity!=""){
                $.ajax({
                    url: "MyCart.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                        StoreID: StoreID,
                        ProductQuantity: ProductQuantity

                    },
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(){
            alert("ok");

                    }
                });
            }
            else{
                alert('Please fill all the field !StoreID: StoreID , ProductQuantity: ProductQuantity');

            }
        });
    });
    </script>




    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: what do you mean by `second time for duplicate value..` ? Can you elaborate more? what problem you are currently facing ?

Comment: Sir, I need to send a shop page to my cart page with the submit button in PHP.  But if I submit a form with PHP it 100% work to send and store to DB. Here is my problem PHP reloading / refreshing the page after submitting a form. I need to avoid this refreshing / reloading.

Comment: `$(".btn").attr("id")` will only ever get you the value of the _first_ element with that class - that’s how the `attr` method _works_. Since you want to get the value of that same button that was just clicked here, you can simply use `$(this).attr("id")` here in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
var buttonsCount = buttons.length;
for (var i = 0; i <= buttonsCount; i += 1) {
buttons[i].onclick = function(e) {
//alert(this.id);
    var targetid= this.id;

    var PImg = $('#PImg_'+targetid).val();
    var PName = $('#PName_'+targetid).val();
    var PRPrice = $('#PRPrice_'+targetid).val();
    var POPrice = $('#POPrice_'+targetid).val();
    var PQ = $('#PQ_'+targetid).val();
    var PSID = $('#PSID_'+targetid).val();

  //alert(this.id+"StoreID"+StoreID+"ProductQuantity"+ProductQuantity);

          if(PSID!="" && PQ!=""){
            $.ajax({
              url: "MyCart.php",
              type: "POST",
              data: {
                PImg: PImg,
                PName: PName,
                PRPrice: PRPrice,
                POPrice: POPrice,
                PQ: PQ,
                PSID: PSID


              },
              cache: false,
              success: function(){
          //alert("ok");
            window.location.reload();
              }
            });
          }
          else{
          //  alert('Please fill all the field !');
          }

    }

};
});
</script>
```

```js
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
    var buttonsCount = buttons.length;
    for (var i = 0; i <= buttonsCount; i += 1) {
    buttons[i].onclick = function(e) {
    //alert(this.id);
        var targetid= this.id;
        
        var PImg = $('#PImg_'+targetid).val();
        var PName = $('#PName_'+targetid).val();
        var PRPrice = $('#PRPrice_'+targetid).val();
        var POPrice = $('#POPrice_'+targetid).val();
        var PQ = $('#PQ_'+targetid).val();
        var PSID = $('#PSID_'+targetid).val();
    
      //alert(this.id+"StoreID"+StoreID+"ProductQuantity"+ProductQuantity);
        
              if(PSID!="" && PQ!=""){
                $.ajax({
                  url: "MyCart.php",
                  type: "POST",
                  data: {
                    PImg: PImg,
                    PName: PName,
                    PRPrice: PRPrice,
                    POPrice: POPrice,
                    PQ: PQ,
                    PSID: PSID
                                        
              
                  },
                  cache: false,
                  success: function(){
              //alert("ok");
                window.location.reload();
                  }
                });
              }
              else{
              //  alert('Please fill all the field !');
              }
        
        }
        
    };
    });
    </script>
```

```html
<?php
session_start();

include 'db.php';
//Get the current page number
if (isset($_GET['pageno'])) {
$pageno = $_GET['pageno'];
} else {
$pageno = 1;
}
//The formula for php pagination
$no_of_records_per_page = 21;
$offset = ($pageno-1) * $no_of_records_per_page;
//Get the number of total number of pages
$result = $mysqli -> query("SELECT * FROM AlmeenaShop ");
$total_rows=$result -> num_rows;
$total_pages = ceil($total_rows / $no_of_records_per_page);
//Constructing the SQL Query for pagination
$ConstructingPagination= $mysqli -> query("SELECT * FROM AlmeenaShop ORDER BY StoreID DESC LIMIT $offset, $no_of_records_per_page");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>Almeena Shop</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="css/shop-homepage.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-----------Nav Bat---------------->
    <div class="container">
      <!-- Navigation Start -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark  text-white">
        
        <H1><span style="color:yellow">Almeena</span> <span style="color:white">Shop</span></H1>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="index.php">Home
                <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a style="color:gold" class="nav-link" href="MyCart.php"><i style="color:gold" class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> <?php echo $ItemCount=count($_SESSION['cart']); ?></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        
      </nav>
    </div>
    <!-- Navigation Start -->
    <div class="container bg-light p-5">
      <!-------####### Carosel Start    ###########-------------------->
      <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide " data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner ">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img src="StoreImg/grocery_3.jpg" height="300"class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="StoreImg/Shopping-basket.jpg" height="300" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="StoreImg/3c.jpg" height="300" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
      <!-------#######   Carosel END ###########-------------------->
    </div> 
    
    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <!--------------------------LEft Cploum For Category Start ---------------------------------------->
        <div class="col-lg-3 mt-5">
          <?php
          $ProductCategoryResult = $mysqli -> query ("SELECT ProductCategory, count(ProductCategory)AS PCC FROM AlmeenaShop GROUP BY ProductCategory ORDER BY ProductCategory");
          
          ?>
          <div class="card border-primary mb-3" style="max-width: 18rem;">
            <div class="card-header"><h5>Our Products</h5></div>
            <div class="card-body text-primary">
              <?php foreach ($ProductCategoryResult as $PCrow){
              ?>
              <div class=" card-title" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#<?php echo $PCrow['ProductCategory']; ?>" ><?php echo $PCrow['ProductCategory']; ?>
                <div class="list-group collapse" id="<?php echo $PCrow['ProductCategory']; ?>" >
                  <ul>
                    <?php
                    $ProductSubCategoryResult = $mysqli -> query("SELECT ProductSubCategory FROM AlmeenaShop WHERE  ProductCategory='".$PCrow['ProductCategory']."' GROUP BY ProductSubCategory ORDER BY ProductSubCategory ");
                    foreach ($ProductSubCategoryResult as $PSCrow){
                    ?>
                    <li><a href="View.php?ProductSubCategory=<?php echo $PSCrow['ProductSubCategory'];?>"><?php echo $PSCrow['ProductSubCategory'];?> </a></li>
                    <?php } ?>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
              <?php } ?>
              <div class=" card-title" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo241">Offer
                <div class="list-group collapse" id="demo241" >
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">--------- </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">--------- </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">--------- </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">--------- </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">--------- </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">--------- </a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /.col-lg-3 -->
          <!--------------------------LEft Cploum For Category End ---------------------------------------->

          <!-----#########################Rignt Cploum For Product Start ############################------>
          <div class="col-lg-9 mt-5">
            <ul class="pagination">
              
              <li class="page-item" ><a class="page-link" href="?pageno=1">First</a></li>
              <li class="page-item <?php if($pageno <= 1){ echo 'disabled'; } ?>">
                <a class="page-link"  href="<?php if($pageno <= 1){ echo '#'; } else { echo "?pageno=".($pageno - 1); } ?>">Prev</a>
              </li>
              <li class=" page-item <?php if($pageno >= $total_pages){ echo 'disabled'; } ?>">
                <a class="page-link" href="<?php if($pageno >= $total_pages){ echo '#'; } else { echo "?pageno=".($pageno + 1); } ?>">Next</a>
              </li>
              <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?pageno=<?php echo $total_pages; ?>">Last</a></li>
            </ul>
            <p>Page <?php echo $total_pages; ?> of <?php echo $pageno; ?></p>
            
            <div class="row">
              <?php foreach ($ConstructingPagination as $row) { ?>
              <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
                <div class="card h-100" >
                  <a href="#"><img class="card-img-top p-2" src="http://almeenashop.com/<?php  echo  $row['ImageLocation'] ; ?>" alt=""></a>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h4 class="card-title">
                      <p  style="color:black" ><?php  echo  $row['ProductName'] ; ?></p>
                    <a class="text-success" href="#">
                      <p style="color:orange">Price :</p>
                      <?php if ($row['OfferPrice']>0): ?>
                      <?php  echo "&#2547; ".  $row['OfferPrice']  ." /-"; ?><br /><del class="text-primary"><?php  echo "&#2547; ".  $row['SalesPrice']  ." /-"; ?></del>
                      <?php else : ?>
                      <?php  echo "&#2547; ".  $row['SalesPrice']  ." /-"; ?>
                      <?php endif ?>
                    </a>
                    </h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="card-footer">
                    <form id="CartForm" name="form1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                      <input type="hidden"  name="PImg" id="PImg_<?php  echo  $row['StoreID'] ; ?>" value="<?php  echo  $row['ImageLocation'] ; ?>">
                      <input type="hidden"  name="PName" id="PName_<?php  echo  $row['StoreID'] ; ?>" value="<?php  echo  $row['ProductName'] ; ?>">
                      <input type="hidden"  name="PRPrice" id="PRPrice_<?php  echo  $row['StoreID'] ; ?>" value="<?php  echo  $row['SalesPrice'] ; ?>">
                      <input type="hidden"  name="POPrice" id="POPrice_<?php  echo  $row['StoreID'] ; ?>" value="<?php  echo  $row['OfferPrice'] ; ?>">
                      <input type="hidden"  name="PQ" id="PQ_<?php  echo  $row['StoreID'] ; ?>" value="1">
                      <input type="hidden"  name="PSID" id="PSID_<?php  echo  $row['StoreID'] ; ?>" value="<?php  echo  $row['StoreID'] ; ?>">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="<?php  echo  $row['StoreID'] ; ?>">Add to Cart</button>  
                    </form>
                    | <a href="Add-to-cart.php?id=3">Details</a>                   
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <?php } ?>
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->
          </div>
          <!-- /.col-lg-9 -->
          <!-----######################----Rignt Cploum For Product End -----##########################---------------->
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.container -->
      <!------- &&&&&&&& Footer Start &&&&&&&&&&&&&&------------>
      <footer id="footer">
        <div class="footer-widget  bg-dark text-white">
          <div class="container pt-4 pb-5">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-2">
                <div class="single-widget">
                  <h5>Service</h5>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Online Help</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Order Status</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Change Location</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">FAQ&rsquo;s</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2">
                <div class="single-widget">
                  <h5>Quock Shop</h5>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">T-Shirt</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Mens</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Womens</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Gift Cards</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Shoes</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2">
                <div class="single-widget">
                  <h5>Policies</h5>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Terms of Use</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Privecy Policy</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Refund Policy</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Billing System</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Ticket System</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2">
                <div class="single-widget">
                  <h5>About Shopper</h5>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Company Information</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Store Location</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Affillate Program</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Copyright</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1">
                <div class="single-widget">
                  <h5>News</h5>
                  <form action="#" class="searchform"><input placeholder="Your email address" type="text" /><button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"></button>
                  <p>Get the most recent updates from<br />
                  our site and be updated your self...</p>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="footer-bottom">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <p class="pull-left">Copyright &copy; 2020 Inc. All rights reserved.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>
    <!------- &&&&&&&& Footer End &&&&&&&&&&&&&&------------>
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
    var buttonsCount = buttons.length;
    for (var i = 0; i <= buttonsCount; i += 1) {
    buttons[i].onclick = function(e) {
    //alert(this.id);
        var targetid= this.id;
        
        var PImg = $('#PImg_'+targetid).val();
        var PName = $('#PName_'+targetid).val();
        var PRPrice = $('#PRPrice_'+targetid).val();
        var POPrice = $('#POPrice_'+targetid).val();
        var PQ = $('#PQ_'+targetid).val();
        var PSID = $('#PSID_'+targetid).val();
    
      //alert(this.id+"StoreID"+StoreID+"ProductQuantity"+ProductQuantity);
        
              if(PSID!="" && PQ!=""){
                $.ajax({
                  url: "MyCart.php",
                  type: "POST",
                  data: {
                    PImg: PImg,
                    PName: PName,
                    PRPrice: PRPrice,
                    POPrice: POPrice,
                    PQ: PQ,
                    PSID: PSID
                                        
              
                  },
                  cache: false,
                  success: function(){
              //alert("ok");
                window.location.reload();
                  }
                });
              }
              else{
              //  alert('Please fill all the field !');
              }
        
        }
        
    };
    });
    </script>

    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is that suppoosed to be the answer/solution to your problem here? If not, then please don’t post it as an _answer_, but edit your question instead, if you wanted to include more code for clarity.